# Error inserting record into table using postGres function json_populate_recordset

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to use the postgres function json_populate_recordset to insert a record into a table from a json string. I created a test table like this:

```
create table users ( f_name varchar(40), email varchar(60), mobile varchar(10), username varchar(40))
```

, then I attempt an insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO users(f_name, email, mobile, username) 
SELECT f_name, email, mobile, username 
FROM json_populate_recordset(null::users, '[{f_name:"Rick",email:"rick@gmail.com", mobile:"240-454-7845", username: "rickyC"}]');
```

, and I get the error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 9: FROM json_populate_recordset(null::users, '[{f_name:"Rick",e...
                                              ^
DETAIL:  Token "f_name" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 3: [{f_name...
SQL state: 22P02
Character: 464
```

I've tried various ways to insert from the function, and it always fails at the first param in the  json string. I would be grateful for any ideas. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new type whose column names correspond to JSON fields, to pass to the function `json_populate_recordset` :

```
CREATE TYPE users_type AS  ( f_name varchar(40), email varchar(60), mobile varchar(20), username varchar(40));
```

Then :

```
INSERT INTO users(f_name, email, mobile, username) 
SELECT f_name, email, mobile, username 
FROM json_populate_recordset(null::users_type, '[{"f_name":"Rick", "email":"rick@gmail.com", "mobile":"240-454-7845", "username": "rickyC"}]');
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/B88VQOss)